# Computer Architecture/Assembly, Amdahl's Law

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture

For a program that is 70% parallelizable, what will be the speedup relative to a uniprocessor from running it on a 4,8 and 16 way multiprocessor assuming perfect load balancing.

So I am having a hard time solving this problem, I know the equation is:

> Improved execution time = affected execution time/(improvement factor
>   + unaffected execution time)

But I am not sure what I should be plugging and why I should or how I should rewrite the equation to solve the problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a picture helps:

```
           +----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
1 core:    |     non-par.   |               parallelizable              |
           |     (1 - Q)    |                      Q                    |
           +----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
                            |
                    ||      |
                            |
           +----------------+----------+    --+
n cores:   |                |          |      |
           +----------------+----------+      |
                            |          |      |
                            +----------+      +-- n times
                            |          |      |
                            +----------+      |
                            |          |      |
                            +----------+    --+


time:      |- (1 - Q) * T  -|------------------ Q * T ------------------|
           |                | Q*T / n  | Q*T / n  | Q*T / n  | Q*T / n  |
```

So if the sequential time is *T* and the fraction *Q* is parallelizable, then the total time it takes when parallelized to *n* cores is (1 − *Q*) * *T* + *Q* * *T* / *n*.

(The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) uses *Q* = 1 − *B*).

Interesting cases are *Q* = 0, when there is no speed-up at all and the algorithm takes time *T* on any number of cores, and *Q* = 1 when the algorithm is perfectly parallel and takes time *T* / *n* on *n* cores.